# How to see what will be merged after git fetch

Tags: git, git-fetch

My question is after doing a `git fetch` how can I see what is what git actually fetched from origin?
I have my guesses by using diff but I don't know exactly how I can do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the fact that after a `git fetch` the fetched references are in `origin/master` (just an example, if you have more branches then they are updated as well as `origin/<name>` and you can apply the following commands as well) you have several options here:

**1. Display file names only that have been changed**

```
git diff --name-only origin/master
```

**2. Display file status only**

```
git diff --name-status origin/master
```

**3. Really show what changed**

```
 git diff origin/master
```

Or you use `git show` for this task:
    git show --oneline --name-only master..origin/master

And for completeness you can use the following command to count commits that where fetched.

```
git rev-list --count HEAD..origin/master
```