# What do ingoing and outgoing mean in RTC (rational team concert)?

Tags: git, rational-team-concert

Can you please explain them using concepts of Git?

Also, is there any situations when operations on outgoing set could be dangerous?

Answer (score 2):

RTC ([Rational Team Concert from IBM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_Team_Concert)) is a *centralized* VCS (Version Control System).
As opposed to [Git](https://git-scm.com/), which is decentralized.
So any direct comparison between the two will be limited and fraught with inaccuracies.

But the closest Git notion you could have from:

- an **outgoing change set** (one that you could deliver from your repo workspace to your RTC steam) would be **Git staged files** (set of files ready to be committed to your current branch,
- an i**ngoing change set** (one that has been published to an RTC stream and is ready to be accepted into your repo workspace) would be what is [ready to be merged after a fetch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31445518/6309): `git diff --name-only origin/master`

As for a delicate operation on change set, one example would be "[Reversing change sets](https://jazz.net/help-dev/clm/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.team.concert.dotnet.doc%2Ftopics%2Ft_reversing_change_sets.html)", which can  remove the changes captured in a change set and create a patch.
See more at "[Managing change sets in RTC](http://blog.royalcyber.com/devops/managing-change-sets-in-rtc/)": discard and suspend can also have an impact on (espacially outgoing) change sets.

Comment: Despite the limitations you outline regaring decentralization vs centralization, I think this is a fair comparison. +1 4 QnA

Answer (score 1):

I'll add that an outgoing change set cannot be delivered on a source member, if the same source member has an incoming change set. You must accept/merge the change set in before you can deliver the outgoing change set.

Other than that, the only other real "danger" is delivering code to a stream when you've not tested your code (i.e. unit tested) locally.